# How to integrate Firebase with Partytown in a Next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, analytics, partytown

I am working on a Next.js project and I want to use `Partytown` to improve the performance of my `Firebase` scripts. Partytown executes scripts in a web worker, and I'm trying to figure out how to set it up so that I can use Firebase's `logEvent` function in my code.

Here's the Firebase script I have (from the Firebase documentation):

```js
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp, logEvent as firebaseLogEvent } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-analytics.js";
  
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

  // I would like to expose this function outside
  const logEvent = (eventName, eventParams) => firebaseLogEvent(analytics, eventName, eventParams);
</script>
```

I've tried wrapping the script with type="text/partytown" and including the Partytown component in my project, but I'm unsure how to expose the logEvent function so that I can use it in my main thread.

```js
<script
  type="text/partytown"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
      // Firebase script here...
    `,
  }}
/>
```

```
<Partytown debug={true} />
```

I want to be able to call logEvent from anywhere in my code like so:

```js
logEvent('event_name', { /* event parameters */ });
```

How can I set this up? Has anyone successfully integrated Firebase with Partytown in a Next.js project? Any help or guidance would be appreciated!